# Passing parameters to method, for accessing a CoreData attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, methods, parameters, arguments

I have customized the CoreDataBooks sample app and am adding a whole host of Bools. Essentially, I am turning it into a restaurant app, so I want to have Bool values for things like "Dinner" "Seafood" "Cocktails" "Kid Friendly" etc..

In my Detailview Controller, I have selected an item (book) and can alter the Bool values in CoreData - for an attribute named seafood, like this -

```
     self.book.seafood = NO;
```

or

```
     self.book.seafood = YES;
```

These values are each toggled with their own button (actually looks like a checkbox in my app)

However, because there may be 60 or 80 Bools, and I'd like to add more later, I'd like to write one function which I can use for all of them that uses a tag or passes a parameter. I'd like to write something like this, but I feel like I am missing a step. It clearly won't let me pass a parameter in to self.book.button:

```
      -(IBAction) switchValue:(*UIButton)button{

      tmpBool = self.book.button

     if (tempBool == YES) {
            self.book.button = NO;

            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkOff.png"];
            [self.button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSLog(@"nwSwitched to NO");
        }
        else{

            self.book.button = YES;

            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkOn.png"];
            [self.button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSLog(@"nwSwitched to YES");
        }
```

As it stands now, the only way I can make it work is with a huge series of if/thens or with switch, but I know there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: More elegant ways involve not using 60-80 `BOOL` variables. In all seriousness that sounds like a recipe for disaster. If you insist, though, try associating each of your buttons with a property name, and then use KVC to set the value. Use a dictionary or associated objects to form the button / key path association.

Comment: This is just a "hobby" app I am building for one friend, so I am not all that worried how sustainable it is, but if you have a suggestion of how to track these items without BOOLS, that would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how you need to customize the behavior based on the properties, but one thought I had is to make another entity called `RestaurantCharacteristic`, and each object would represent something like "Dinner", "Kid Friendly", etc. Then every `Restaurant` could have a to-many relationship with the characteristics, and so checking which are in that set replaces checking properties on restaurants. Alternatively, [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) seems applicable. Of course for hobby app maybe not worth it, depending on how far along you are :)

Answer (score 0):

As Carl said, this was an inelegant approach. I instead switched and now keep all the tags in one CoreData attribute called "tags". To add and subtract them I simply add to the string or find a replace with @" ", to remove them. I can then search against them later.

In order to manage the long list of tags, and to add to them easily, I used a PickerView, which is set using an NSMutableArray, which I store in NSUserDefaults. (You have to make a mutable copy when you re-load it.)

Yes, you could keep the list of tags in CoreData, but this seemed easier for my purposes.